# How do I publish to the public npm registry, if I have a private registry setup already?

Tags: npm

As the title says:  I have a private registry set up in my npm config, but I want a certain repo published to the public registry.

According to the [`npm registry`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) docs,

> If you then want to publish a package for the whole world to see, you can simply override the `--registry` option for that `publish` command.

However, the [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) docs don't mention a `--registry` option..